# Multiply specific rows if sum of columns fulfils criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with four columns and want to multiply only the float numbers of each row that have a sum less than 0.9 by the same amount until the sum of each row is equal to 0.9. The rows where the sum is already above 0.9 should not be touched.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.03, 0.0, 0.4],
           'B': [0.1234, 0.4, 0.333],
           'C': [0.5, 0.4, 0.0333],
           'D': [0.8, 0.2, 0.2]})
```

Orignal dataframe:

```
A B C D
0 0.03 0.1234 0.5000 0.8 
1 0.00 0.4000 0.4000 0.2 
2 0.40 0.3330 0.0333 0.2
```

Column sum:

```
A: 0.43
B: 0.7564
C: 0.9333
D: 1.2
```

Outcome: The cells where the sum of the column was lower than 0.9 were multiplied so that the sum of all three cells of each column is 0.9. It is important that the cells which are 0 would stay 0, this should not be touched.
So in this case column A,B, and C must be adjusted.

Comment: `only the float numbers of each row` one column cannot have multiple data types. So either the values are floats or ints

Comment: What have you tried? Demonstrate some effort in solving the issue.

Comment: The logic behind is not clear to me. Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @yatu, please assume all are floats

Comment: @rpanai I have tried this so far df.mul(0.9/df.sum(axis=1),axis=0) which helped to do the job but it included all rows and not only the rows which had a sum below 0.9

Comment: @rpanai The print (df) is the desired outcome

Comment: I don't see how `df.mul(0.9/df.sum(axis=1),axis=0)` produce the desired output.

Comment: I corrected the original questions..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making some confusion between rows and columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.03, 0.0, 0.4],
           'B': [0.1234, 0.4, 0.333],
           'C': [0.5, 0.4, 0.0333],
           'D': [0.8, 0.2, 0.2]})

print(df)

      A       B       C    D
0  0.03  0.1234  0.5000  0.8
1  0.00  0.4000  0.4000  0.2
2  0.40  0.3330  0.0333  0.2
```

as `df.sum(1)` returns

```
0    1.4534
1    1.0000
2    0.9663
dtype: float64
```

while `df.sum()` returns

```
A    0.4300
B    0.8564
C    0.9333
D    1.2000
dtype: float64
```

So if you want to use `df.mul(0.9/df.sum())` only for columns where the sum is less than `0.9` you could use `np.where`

```py
out = np.where(df.sum()<0.9, df.mul(0.9/df.sum()), df)
out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=df.columns)
```

which returns

```py
print(out)

          A         B       C    D
0  0.062791  0.129682  0.5000  0.8
1  0.000000  0.420364  0.4000  0.2
2  0.837209  0.349953  0.0333  0.2
```